# Why does the installation of Ubuntu is taking 4 hours?

Tags: system-installation

I would like to know, how much time is required to install Ubuntu? This is because my computer takes 4 to 5 hours to install Ubuntu 13.04 trough the USB.

I have no problem to install Windows 7 (takes only 30 minutes).

What is actually the problem? Because I am interested in using Ubuntu rather than Windows

My computer specs: Intel Dual Core 1.7Ghz 2GB RAM, 60GBHDD

Comment: Hello! Welcome to AskUbuntu. Do you mind providing the details of your computer? such as microprocessor model and speed, amount of RAM, HDD and as much details as possible in order to determine if you are experiencing some hardware related issue or not. Additionally, please let us know if you have tried with a different disc and/or a different CD/DVD reader, if you are using a USB for the install please let us know. This details will be useful in order to get the best support for you. Remember that a corrupted disc or a dirty lens in your CD/DVD reader will make a major difference.

Comment: adding to above: also take not of ANY messages that appear on the screen (you can switch consoles with control-alt-f[1:7]).

Comment: Intel Dual Core 1.7Ghz 2GB RAM, 60GBHDD

i also use different iso... For your information, i install through usb drive.. have try another usb drive.. same problem

Comment: Takes about 30 minutes, it may take longer if you choose to update when you install, if you install the additional repositories, and if you are resizing a large partition. Can you give us more information ? What step is taking the most time.

Comment: I installed Ubuntu on a Pentium III, and it didn't take but 42 minutes.  In your question, you say that your hard drive is 60GB, how much of that is for Ubuntu?  Are you installing 32bit or 64bit Ubuntu?

Comment: Did you try another USB port? Is it possible you caould be using a USB 1.1 port?

Answer (score 1):

It should take about half an hour to install Ubuntu. If it takes four hours, something has gone wrong. [Make sure your checksums match](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) before installing.